# which way of grouping table elements is better for easy changes update, row or column

Tags: adobe-illustrator

while creating table elements in illustrator which way of grouping the table elements is better whether to group it in a row wise or column wise? For Easy changes in table content

Answer (score 1):

Whichever works for you.

There's no "best" way in Illustrator since there's no direct support for actual tables. It all ends up as text with tabs and line feeds. If it's easier for you to edit tabs, use rows. If it's easier to edit columns use line feeds.

I, personally, use both...

`Item ---- tab ---- Item --- tab -- item (feed)
Item ---- tab ---- Item --- tab -- item (feed)
Item ---- tab ---- Item --- tab -- item (feed)
Item ---- tab ---- Item --- tab -- item (feed)`

Then you can adjust positioning for all rows via leading or space before/after returns... and you can adjust column spacing by changing tabs.

If the table content is more than merely text... then it's still your callas to which is easier for you to edit.